# div enlargement transition from https://gourmethouse.com/contact

Tags: css, transition

Does anyone know to make this effect where the div enlarges when hovered on and the others moves away likes this: https://gourmethouse.com/contact?

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that your question still hasn't a marked solution. Is this because you simply forgot or is your question still unanswered? I'd be happy to help you further with your case, otherwhise please mark this question as solved as it helps other users for a better experience on stackoverflow.

Comment: Oh no. Your help worked. Sorry. I'm unaware that I had to do that. I'm changing it to marked solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this question is way to broad to receive an answer. You are lucky though. I was really interested in trying it out myself and I found it rather easy. I made you a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2uvfsy1b/10/

Basically all you need to do is to use a little JQuery (or javascript if you're more familiar) to set the width of the hovered element to (in my case 40%) and the width of all the other elements to (in my case 20%). As long as the total sum equals 100% the effect works out fine.

**Here's an explanation for the code:**

```
$(".enlargeHover").hover(
  function() {
    $(".enlargeHover").css("width", "20%");
    $(this).css("width", "40%");
  }
);
```

The above snippet is all of the JQuery stuff you will need. It sets the width of all elements with the class `enlargeHover` to 20% while it sets the width of the one element you're currently hovering to 40%. (20% + 20% + 20% + 40% = 100%).

```
<div class="enlargeHover img1">
  Lorem
</div>
<div class="enlargeHover img2">
  Ipsum
</div>
<div class="enlargeHover img3">
  Dolor
</div>
<div class="enlargeHover img4">
  Sit amet
</div>
```

The above snippet is the used html structure. I used the same class (enlargeHover) to controll the widths of all elements. "img1", "img2" etc are classes that controll the background images.

```
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.enlargeHover {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}

.enlargeHover.img1 {
  background-image: url("https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg");
}

.enlargeHover.img2 {
  background-image: url("http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg");
}

.enlargeHover.img3 {
  background-image: url("https://www.visioncritical.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/BLG_Andrew-G.-River-Sample_09.13.12.png");
}

.enlargeHover.img4 {
  background-image: url("https://kbob.github.io/images/sample-4.jpg");
}
```

The last part is the css one. basically all I did was setting a fixed width of 25% (as 25 * 4 equals 100) and a css transition (for the smoothness effect).

That's all of it.

You can ask for help anytime if you have any further question. I hope I could help.

Comment: I apologize for the broad question, I honestly don't know how to specifically ask the question. haha But thank you very much for the answer. This really is a great help. Appreciate it!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!